# Como ingreso esta consulta en laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Alguien que me ayude por favor en ingresar esta consulta en Laravel.

```
select a.actividad,p.actividad predecesor,p2.actividad predecesor2,a.fecini,a.fecfin,name, cast(if(100/count(t.id) is null,0,100/count(t.id))*count(case when t.estado="Realizado" then 1 end) as int)/100 as avance from actividades a  left join predecesores p on a.id=p.idactividad left join predecesores p2 on a.id=p2.idactividad inner join users u on a.idusuario=u.id left join tareas t on a.id=t.idactividad where idproyecto=1 and p2.actividad is null or p.actividad!=p2.actividad group by a.actividad union all select a.actividad,p.actividad predecesor,NULL predecesor2,a.fecini,a.fecfin,name, cast(if(100/count(t.id) is null,0,100/count(t.id))*count(case when t.estado="Realizado" then 1 end) as int)/100 as avance  from actividades a inner join predecesores p on a.id=p.idactividad inner join users u on a.idusuario=u.id left join tareas t on a.id=t.idactividad where a.actividad not in  (select a.actividad from actividades a   left join predecesores p on a.id=p.idactividad  left join predecesores p2 on a.id=p2.idactividad  where idproyecto=1 and p2.actividad is null or p.actividad<>p2.actividad  group by a.actividad) and idproyecto=1 group by a.actividad order by 4
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puedes utilizar DB, TU consulta seria de esta forma:  $CONSULTA=DB::select("aqui tu consulta");  Pero para poder utilizar "DB", debes hacer uso de el,de  esta forma: use DB; (esto lo añades al comenzar el archivo php en laravel)

Answer (score -1):

-
Utiliza Raw Sql Queries! debido a que tu consulta es larga.
Usa el Facade DB y el metodo select que te devolvera un resultado a 
diferencia del metodo statement.

- $consulta = \DB::select("select a.actividad,p.actividad predecesor,p2.actividad predecesor2,a.fecini,a.fecfin,name, cast(if(100/count(t.id) is null,0,100/count(t.id))*count(case when t.estado="Realizado" then 1 end) as int)/100 as avance from actividades a  left join predecesores p on a.id=p.idactividad left join predecesores p2 on a.id=p2.idactividad inner join users u on a.idusuario=u.id left join tareas t on a.id=t.idactividad where idproyecto=1 and p2.actividad is null or p.actividad!=p2.actividad group by a.actividad union all select a.actividad,p.actividad predecesor,NULL predecesor2,a.fecini,a.fecfin,name, cast(if(100/count(t.id) is null,0,100/count(t.id))*count(case when t.estado="Realizado" then 1 end) as int)/100 as avance  from actividades a inner join predecesores p on a.id=p.idactividad inner join users u on a.idusuario=u.id left join tareas t on a.id=t.idactividad where a.actividad not in  (select a.actividad from actividades a   left join predecesores p on a.id=p.idactividad  left join predecesores p2 on a.id=p2.idactividad  where idproyecto=1 and p2.actividad is null or p.actividad<>p2.actividad  group by a.actividad) and idproyecto=1 group by a.actividad order by 4");

Comment: Gracias por ayudarme a ser un mejor colaborador, esta mejor?

Comment: El "codigo" que has puesto se ha quedado sin formato y esta todo pegado, puedes intentar ponerlo con formato? si no queda muy mal a la vista